# How to automatically fill the space in a line in IEEE trans?

Tags: ieeetran, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to insert a figure inside a subsubsection. Now after successfully inserting the figure i saw that my texts are not formatting quite nicely.

[image].

As shown in the figure the line **As they showed expermentally** is in one line but it is giving a gap between as i insert a figure between them. But i don't want that gap. I want that the paragraph with the figure will automatically format.

My code:

```
\subsubsection{Measuring the objectness of image windows}
B. Alexe et al. \cite{1} presented a generic objectness measure, quantifying how likely it is for an image window to contain an object of any
class. They explicitly trained it to distinguish objects with a well-defined boundary in space, such as cows and telephones, from amorphous
background elements, such as grass and road. The measure combines in a Bayesian framework several image cues measuring characteristics of objects, such as appearing
from their surroundings and having a closed boundary. These include an
innovative cue to measure the closed boundary characteristic. Finally, they presented two applications of objectness. In the first, they sample a small number windows according to their
objectness probability and gave an algorithm to employ them as location priors for modern class-specific object detectors. As they showed

\begin{figure}[!htb] 
    \centering
  \subfloat[a]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/obj1}}
    \label{obj1}
  \subfloat[b]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/obj2}}
    \label{obj2}
  \caption{Segmented Images}
        \vspace{-.5cm}
  \label{objectnessfig} 
\end{figure}

experimentally, this greatly reduces the number of windows evaluated by the expensive class-specific model. In the second application,
they used objectness as a complementary score in addition to the class-specific model, which leads to fewer false positives. As shown in
several recent papers, objectness can act as a valuable focus of attention mechanism in many other applications operating on image
windows, including weakly supervised learning of object categories, unsupervised pixelwise segmentation, and object tracking in video.
Computing objectness is very efficient and takes only about 4 sec. per image. This technique finds out some image windows like Figure \ref{objectnessfig}.
```

How can i write the line without having that much space having a figure between them??

Comment: plz clear this things to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the blank lines before and after the  `figure` environment and your problem is solved. You have written two paragraphs. One ending with "As they showed" and another starting  with "experimentally". One or more blank lines between text is equivalent to a `\par` control sequence.

In general, is better place the figures between true paragraphs and without forcing places (`htb`) and avoiding LaTeX rules (`!`). Try without `[!htb]` and only add some option in some image *in the final version* when you disagree with the placement of the figures. Otherwise, left to LaTeX work for you.

Comment: but if i don't use [!htb] then it places my image elsewhere. It doesn't place the figure inside the paragraph

Comment: That is the point, usually LaTeX find a better place that you `:)`, but if you what the image just here, use `h`ere, not `t`op or `b`ottom options.

Comment: I am facing another problem here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306973/why-algorithm-table-is-stretching-in-two-columns-in-ieee-trans