# Why second column in IEEE trans is not filling up?

Tags: ieeetran, algorithm2e

I am trying to include my algorithm into one column of a two column format of IEEE trans. My code is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
Computing objectness is very efficient and takes only about 4 sec. per image. This technique finds out some image windows like Figure \ref{objectnessfig}.\\
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\begin{description}\itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt \vspace{.1cm}
  \item[Input:] \(F, D, c\) 
  \item[Ouput:] \(Det\)
  \item[Step 1:] \( \l = \left \{ w_{1},...,w_{F} \right \}, w_{i}\rightarrow D, \forall_{i} \)
  \item[Step 2:] \( \l_{s} = \left \{ \left ( w_{1},sw_{1} \right ),...,\left ( w_{F},sw_{F} \right )  \right \}, sw_{i}= c\left ( w_{i} \right ), \forall_{i} \) 
  \item[Step 3:] \( \rho _{s} = NMS\left ( \l_{s} \right )=\left \{ \left ( w_{n1},sw_{n1} \right ),...,\left ( w_{np},sw_{np} \right )  \right \}\)
  \item[Step 4:] \(\L=\left \{ w_{n1}^{lm},..., w_{np}^{lm} \right \}, w_{nj}^{lm} = max \left ( s_{w} \right )\)
  \item[Step 5:] \(Det = NMS\left ( \L \right )\)
\end{description}
\caption{Using objectness for class-specific detectors.}
\end{algorithm}
The general scheme for using their objectness measure as
a location prior for object detectors is algorithm 1. The
algorithm inputs the class-specific confidence function \(c\) which
the detector employs to score a window.
They build an initial set \(\l\) of \(F = 1000\) windows multinomially sampled from the distribution \(D\) of windows scored by
their objectness measure (Multi-scale Saliency)\(MS\) +(Color Contrast)\(CC\) + (Superpixels Straddling)\(SS\) (step 1). They use \(c\) to
score each window in \(\l\) (step 2). They then run the non-maxima
suppression. This results in a set \(\rho_{s}\) of promising
windows (step 3). For every window \(w_{p} \epsilon \rho_{s}\), they iteratively
move to the local maximum of \(c\) in its neighborhood \(V_{w
p}\),
resulting in window \(w_{p}^{lm}\) (step 4). Finally, they run \(NMS\) on the
local maxima windows \(\L\) and obtain detections \(Det\) (step 5).
In order to use this algorithm one has to specify a window
scoring function \(c\), which is specific to a particular detector
and object class, and a window neighborhood.
```

But the problem is i got this below result.
[image]

I don't know why the space is vacant beside the algorithm. If i comment out the algorithm then it becomes ok. What's the problem actually??

**Edit: When i use \Blindtext then the algo table is placed nicely but when i give my text then it show the above problem.**

I got the same problem for a table also where i want the table to remain in one column.[image] .
 But when i use \Blindtext then it is okay.
[image]

Below is the code i used for table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Result for the sample image for Selective Search}
\label{ressel}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hline
Labels      & Label-1 & Label-2 & Label-3 & Label-4 \\ \hline
Top-1       & bird    & cat     & frog    & dog           \\ \hline
Top-2       & cat     & bird    & dog     & frog           \\ \hline
Cumulative  & cat     & frog    & bird    & dog            \\ \hline
Total Score & cat     & frog    & bird    & dog           \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Please give us a minimal code which clearly shows this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what needs you to reproduce it again?? Is there any problem in the algorithm package i have used here??

Comment: Well, I have taken your code, added the missing `\begin{document}\end{document}` and finally the package `\usepackage{blindtext}` in order to do a `\Blindext` command in the end of your code. Like this, I got a two columns document which does not show your issue. We cannot guess what is happening with your document, if we cannot the the issue.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16123884/ .. look at this link plz

Comment: This code is not minimal and not complete. And if I insert it in the above mentioned code, I do not get a blank space. Please try not to use external links here, as we cannot control whats behind that. Please see: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: seriously i am in fix what shoul i give you. This code inside my my whole paper

Comment: I saw that if i use \Blindtext then no problem but if i write my paper text it is showing in the erroneous way

Comment: It is not clear whether you want the algorithm to remain within one column or to be across the whole page?

Comment: I want the algorithm to remain within one column

Comment: The problem is  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}. it must be 50% ie. \begin{tabularx}{0.45\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}

Comment: This is not working..  @murugan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `\usepackage{stfloats}`. Removing the package solved my issue.

Comment: The information was missing from the question. Voted to close.